# &object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1

Tags: php

I'm trying to store an integer value in session like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['images'])){

   if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
         $_SESSION['images'] = array();
         array_push($_SESSION['images'], (int)$newFilename );
   }
 } else {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
             array_push($_SESSION['images'], (int)$newFilename);
             file_put_contents("upload.txt", (int)$newFilename);
        }
   }
```

but the same code works on my localhost (php 5.3.13) but doesn't work on the hosting with php 5.2.17 (this is the only difference I can see here).
I know that there are some problems with storing objects in $_SESSION, but i'm thrying to store there just a one-dimensional array like this:

```
$newFilename = $images->getLastFileId();
//$newFilename == array['200','201', '202'...n];
```

When $_SESSION['images'] has one element, all works correctly, but if there are >1 elements, I have an error `&object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1`, and `var_dump($_SESSION)` shows that I have an object (looks like php tries to store in `$newFilename` an object `$images`):

```
array(1) { ["images"]=> &object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1 (9) {     ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(15) "ImageCollection" ["imgSize"]=> 
 string(0) "" ["imgAngle"]=> string(0) "" ["imgUrl"]=> string(0) "" 
 ["imgDir"]=> string(7) "upload/" ["thumbDir"]=> string(9) 
 "upload/m/" ["imgPreviewDir"]=> string(0) "" ["avatarsWidth"]=> int(50) 
["avatarsDir"]=> string(8) "avatars/" } }
```

Again, this code works correctly on my localhost. Where could be the problem?

**UPDATE** I solved problem, but I'm not quite sure what causes this problem. Maybe it's php bug, but my code starts to work correctly after I renamed `$_SESSION['images']`  into  `$_SESSION['imagesNew']` - so name of the $_SESSION variable is no longer the same as the name of the variable $images.

Comment: That usually happens when you're trying to unserialize an object for which the definition has not been loaded yet.

Comment: I know, but this is not an object, this is just an array.

Comment: can you enable display_errors? are there other error messages?

Comment: @cryptic note that `==` isn't an assignment. Me understanding this line as a comment. @user1858864 shouldn't I?

Comment: yes, display_errors are enabled, this is only error.

Comment: @hek2mgl, you`re absolutely right, this is just a comment to show, what I'm trying to store in this array. I've corrected post, thanks.

Comment: can you provide more info on the usage of `ImageCollection`? When is this class used?

Comment: @hek2mgl, this is large file, which uses this class almost every line, but typical use of this class is about get file, move them into other dir, resize and rotate it, and no work with sessions.

Comment: Try `require_once 'path/to/ImageCollection.php';` at the very beginning of the file(s); Does it work now?

Comment: @hek2mgl no, everything remains the same. But in comments below Jack suggested, that problem should be in other place in code. So, thanks for you help and attention)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR - the code you've shown shouldn't exhibit this behaviour, therefore it must be caused somewhere else.

For more information about the symptoms, imagine you have this class definition:

```
class Test
{
  private $x = 'hello';
}
```

Let's serialize that:

```
file_put_contents('serialized.txt', serialize(new Test));
```

File contents (don't try to copy/paste this, it won't work):

```
O:4:"Test":1:{s:7:"Testx";s:5:"hello";}
```

Now, in another script, let's `unserialize()` that (without the class definition):

```
var_dump(unserialize(file_get_contents('serialized.txt')));
```

Output:

```
object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1 (2) {
  ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=>
  string(4) "Test"
  ["x":"Test":private]=>
  string(5) "hello"
}
```

Although your posted code doesn't seem to suggest it, the output you've shown is that of an array of `ImageCollection` objects, so for that to work you need to `require` the definition first, e.g.:

```
require 'imagecollection.class.php';
// open your session here
```

Or use an [`autoloader`](http://www.php.net/spl_autoload).

Comment: Jack, so, I have to require class file even if $_SESSION['images] is not an copy of this class, but is array with integers, wich are result of class methods, right?

Comment: @user1858864 Your code shows that you're only storing integers, so that `var_dump()` output suggests that *something else* is messing with your session data ... or it was there before and you just need to clear your cookies :)

Comment: Jack, but I want to store there integers. :) And when I store there one int, all works correctly, but when I'm trying to push there more ints, I get this error. I'm confused because this code correctly works on my local server.

Comment: @user1858864 Well, I would guess that some code does this: `$_SESSION['images'] = $images`. Otherwise, I would suggest to a) clear cookies and make sure the session is clean before you test, and b) reduce the code to a bare minimum if that fails and `var_dump()` every variable that you add to `$_SESSION`.

Comment: also: http://php.net/function.unserialize - Check the note for `unserialize_callback_func` - http://php.net/var.configuration

Comment: @ Jack, I think, problem somewhere in othere code. Nevertheless, thank you for your help, now I know, that I should search problem in another my code. :)

Comment: @user1858864 Good luck, keep us updated when you have found the issue :)